# How can I utilize normal maps on objects lacking tangent vertex attributes?

Tags: graphics, rendering, textures, vulkan, hlsl

I am working on loading gltf models in my 3d rendering application and am trying to implement support for normal mapping.

When inspecting the [Antique Camera](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/AntiqueCamera) (part of their [core model showcase](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0#showcase)) I noticed that it doesn't have a tangent vertex attribute. I'm a bit confused as to how I can perform normal mapping on an object that doesn't have any vertex tangents.

If I see that a model doesn't have any vertex tangents should I try to approximate them when loading that model? Is there another way to utilize normal maps without using tangent space and a TBN matrix?

I have tried approximating the tangent for each vertex like so:

```
glm::vec3 t = glm::cross(normal, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::vec3 t2 = glm::cross(normal, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::vec3 t3 = glm::cross(normal, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

if (glm::length(t2) > glm::length(t)) {
    t = t2;
}
if (glm::length(t3) > glm::length(t)) {
    t = t3;
}

tangent = glm::normalize(t);
```

but this results in varying behavior based on the model (weird behavior when loading a simple cube but seemingly correct behavior on more complex models).

I feel it is probably worthwhile to share my shader code (hlsl) so here is how I am calculating the TBN matrix in the vertex shader:

```
vec3 T = normalize(vec3(pushConstant.modelMatrix * vec4(in_tangent, 0.0)));
vec3 N = normalize(vec3(pushConstant.modelMatrix * vec4(in_normal, 0.0)));

T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N); // Reorthogonalize T with respect to N

vec3 B = normalize(cross(N, T)); // Prob don't need to normalize bc T & N are normalized

out_fragmentTBN = mat3(T, B, N);
```

and here is how I am calculating the normal using the TBN matrix in the fragment shader:

```
// get the normal displacement from the normal map
vec3 normalDisplacement = texture(
    sampler2D(
        baseColorTextures[pushConstant.normalTextureID],
        baseColorTextureSampler
    ),
    in_baseColorTextureCoordinate
).rgb;

// convert it to be [-1, 1] from [0, 1]
normalDisplacement = normalize((normalDisplacement * 2.0) - 1.0);

// convert it to tangent space
vec3 normal = normalize(in_fragmentTBN * normalDisplacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Using MikkTSpace to calculate vertex tangents if they aren't present. Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/mmikk/MikkTSpace.git

Comment: add long answer